# Add default value to pivot table (users_roles) when creating a new user

Tags: laravel-5, pivot-table

Been searching the internet to get an answer to my problem but can't find it :-(

I created a Roles/Permissions ability in my Laravel project by taking a videocourse. It uses pivot tables.
My database contains the following standard Laravel tables after php artisan make:auth (and migrate):

- users
- password_resets

For the roles/permissions ability I created the following tables:

- roles (id, name)
- permissions (id, name)
- roles_permissions (role_id, permission_id)
- users_roles (user_id, role_id)
- users_permissions (user_id, permission_id)

I also created a Trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Permissions;

use App\{Role, Permission};

trait HasPermissionsTrait
{
    public function givePermissionTo(...$permissions)
    {
        $permissions = $this->getAllPermissions(array_flatten($permissions));

    if ($permissions === null) {
        return $this;
    }

    $this->permissions()->saveMany($permissions);

    return $this;
}

public function withdrawPermissionTo(...$permissions)
{
    $permissions = $this->getAllPermissions(array_flatten($permissions));

    $this->permissions()->detach($permissions);

    return $this;
}

public function updatePermissions(...$permissions)
{
    $this->permissions()->detach();

    return $this->givePermissionTo($permissions);;
}

public function hasRole(...$roles)
{
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if ($this->roles->contains('name', $role)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public function hasPermissionTo($permission)
{
    return $this->hasPermissionThroughRole($permission) || $this->hasPermission($permission);
}

protected function hasPermissionThroughRole($permission)
{
    foreach ($permission->roles as $role) {
        if ($this->roles->contains($role)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

protected function hasPermission($permission)
{
    return (bool) $this->permissions->where('name', $permission->name)->count();
}

protected function getAllPermissions(array $permissions)
{
    return Permission::whereIn('name', $permissions)->get();
}

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'users_roles');
}

public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'users_permissions');
}

public function giveRoleTo(...$roles)
{
    $roles = $this->getAllRoles(array_flatten($roles));

    if ($roles === null) {
        return $this;
    }

    $this->roles()->saveMany($roles);

    return $this;
}

public function withdrawRoleTo(...$roles)
{
    $roles = $this->getAllRoles(array_flatten($roles));

    $this->roles()->detach($roles);

    return $this;
}

public function updateRoles(...$roles)
{
    $this->roles()->detach();

    return $this->giveRoleTo($roles);;
}
```

}

My UsersController look like this (the create method):

```
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'achternaam'  => request('achternaam'),
        'voorletters' => request('voorletters'),
        'district_id' => request('district_id'),
        'gemeente_id' => request('gemeente_id'),
        'minister_id' => request('minister_id'),
        'periode_van' => request('periode_van'),
        'periode_tot' => request('periode_tot'),
        'email'       => request('email'),
        'password'    => bcrypt(request('password')),
        'active'      => false
    ]);

    return redirect('/home')->withInfo('Een account activatie mail is verstuurd.');;

}
```

What I would like to do is to give a newly created user a default role of user (id='10', name='user' in the users_roles table).

When I use the method roles() to create a new record for that newly created user I get an error saying that the column 'role' does not exist in the roles table. Which is true because it only has an id & name column.

Can someone tell me why? And even better give me some code example to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not worked in trait but I got something for you. There is a library called entrust in laravel. I have worked on this kind of concepts using following tutorial. Just check out this tutorial ->http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-52-user-acl-roles-and-permissions-with-middleware-using-entrust-from-scratch-tutorialexample.html. It will give you a clear picture of role/permission.

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look at it